# Derive UIC generated Qt UI class from custom interface

Tags: qt, user-interface, interface, generator

I've a simple Qt Question. I want that automatically generated UIC files are derived from a custom interface class like in:

**Intention**

```
class MyUiInterface {
public:
     virtual void setupUi(QWidget* w) = 0;
     virtual void retranslateUi(QWidget*w) = 0;
};
```

Generated UIC file should look like:

```
class Ui_MyWidget {
public:
    void setupUi(QWidget* w) {
        ...
    }
    void retranslateUi(QWidget* w) {
        ...
    }
};

namespace Ui {
    class MyWidget : public MyUiInterface , public Ui_MyWidget {};
}
```

**Why?**

Every Ui::Class would then implement MyUiInterface. In each class that derives from Ui::Class (see [The Multiple Inheritance Approach](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/designer-using-a-ui-file.html)) I would be able to call `setupUi` and `retranslateUi` which makes sense if the class that derives from UI::Class class is a base class either. I want every widget to be derived from my abstrcat base class `MyWidgetBase`. Consider following:

```
class MyWidgetBase abstract : public QWidget, protected MyUiInterface {
protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e) {
        QWidget::changeEvent(e);
        if (e->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
            retranslateUi(this); // Still abstract here
        }
    }
};

class MyWidget : public MyWidgetBase : public Ui::MyWidget {
};
```

The effect is, every time MyWidget::changeEvent() is callled, `retranslateUi` of that specific class is called. Otherwise changeEvent had to be reimplemented in each class. This would be a bit against "code reuse" concept.

I think Qt UIC is not able to handle this situation isn't it? Is there a similar way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, reading [XML Schema for ui files](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-ui-file-format.html) is telling us that this is not possible to automate using uic compiler.

However, it is unclear to me why you would want to implement that automatically - even if the Uic somehow manages to implement your interface, you will still need to add bodies of the functions by hand, editing generated .h file, as I am sure that there is no way to include custom code in xml file which will translate as C++ code.

Why you just don't reimplement `setupUi` and `retranslateUi` in your `MyWidget` class? Every Ui class will have one of these classes, so you can implement this on this level, instead of base class. It is possible that I am missing something, but I see this as an appropriate way to do this.

```
class MyWidget : public MyWidgetBase, public Ui::MyWidget {
public:
    void setupUi(QWidget* w) {
        ...
    }
    void retranslateUi(QWidget* w) {
        ...
    }

};
```

With this approach, you don't need to reimplement `changeEvent()` in any of your custom widgets, and `changeEvent` will still call the appropriate `retranslateUi()`.

Comment: Ok, I think what you mean is make setupUi and retranslateUi as virtual methods in MyWidgetBase class and implement it in MyWidget (and all others derived from MyWidgetBase) by calling Ui::MyWidget::setupUi(this) there. This would indeed be a solution. With my solution it is not required to edit generated header files by the way _if_ the UI compiler would work as I intent :)

Comment: @bkausbk Unfortunately, unless someone here doesn't know any hack how to do this, I don't think it is possible - but let's see, I saw plenty of stuff working afterall :)